# Random forest for binary panel data

Tags: r, bootstrap, random-forest, panel-data, random-effects-model

I have a dataset with observations from about 50 countries and 20 years. My dependent variable is **binary** and I was wondering if I could use random forest to do out-of-sample predictions. My problem is: as far as I know, RF considers observations to be independent, which is not the case in my dataset. Is there any software (preferably an R package) that takes data structure into consideration when doing bootstrap sampling? I was thinking about something like `GMERT`, random effects combined with RF (see: [How can I include random effects into a randomForest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103730/how-can-i-include-random-effects-into-a-randomforest)). However, due to my limited programming skills, I could not adapt the authors' code to use it with binary response variables. Any suggestions?

Comment: *Time-series cross-section* in the title plus how you describe your problem calls for a `panel-data` tag, and perhaps changing the title into something like "Random forest for panel data". Hopefully, that would help you attract the right people to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, @RichardHardy! I've just edited the title as you suggested.

Comment: I am developing these methods and will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Randel. Please let me know when your code is ready and if I can help you with something.

Comment: Is there an analogous package in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function for [Mixed Logistic Random Forest for Binary Data](https://github.com/randel/MixRF/blob/master/R/MixRFb.r). The usage is demonstrated with an example within the link. The prediction function is also available.

Following Hajjem's generalized mixed effects regression trees (GMERT), I used an EM-like algorithm and penalized quasi-likelihood (PQL) estimation.

- The random forest part uses `cforest()` in the `party` package since it allows case weights.
- The linearized mixed models are estimated with the `lme4` package. So there are many possible options.

Comment: The function works great, @Randel! That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @danilofreire great! If possible, I'd like to see the performance and comparison with other methods. We can discuss. :)

Comment: Cool, I'd love to help! Feel free to send me a message with any benchmark test or analysis you want me to run. Ah, and be sure that you'll get a big thank you in my future paper's acknowledgement section :)