# Mixed effects in Random forest (in R)

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-forest, meta-analysis

Is it possible to include mixed effects into a random forest model in R? I know about the `lmer` (from `lme4`) and `randomForest` (from randomForest) functions but it would be nice if I could combine the two in some way, if that makes sense.

I'm afraid that if I don't include random effects in my random forest model, it will be incorrect.

Comment: Can you provide some information about your data & problem. Obviously @utobi presumed that your study is longitudinal but I'm not sure how the information in the question supports this guess.

Answer (score 12):

The current main popular implementation of Random Forests (RF) (i.e. the `randomForest` package) is available only for univariate (continuous or discrete) responses. On the other hand, mixed models are inherently multivariate models, that is models that deal with vector-valued responses. Fortunately, extensions of RF for multivariate responses, in particular for handling longitudinal data, do exist.

`LongitudiRF` is one of the  `R` packages that implement Random Forests for longitudinal data of which I am aware. A lot more information can be found at [this](https://doi.org/10.1093/bib/bbad002) recent review paper on longitudinal data with Random Forests.

Related posts:

[How can I include random effects (or repeated measures) into a randomForest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/103730/56940)

[How to deal with hierarchical / nested data in machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221358/56940)

[Random forest for binary panel data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/156600/56940)

Comment: I read it as “luckily…do not exist”.

Comment: replaced "luckily". hopefully, it sounds better now :-)