# random forest analysis with random(clustering) varible

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

My data  consists of presence/absence  (PA) of a trait in 354 plants collected from 127 collection sites as response, and a set of 25 climatic  continuous variables in each site as predictors. The sample size for each collection site ranges from 1 to 4 plants. My goal is to find the climatic variables that are the best predictors of the PA pattern. As expected, the climate data is highly correlated.  I would like to use the random forest approach to find the variables.

I have 3 questions:

1. In gee-glm (generalized estimating equations) one can use a mixed
   model with the collection site as clustering variable (random
   effect) . Is there a way or a need to define such random effect in
   random forest analysis or I can just add the collection site as a
   factor to the predictors?
2. Alternatively, I can calculate the frequency of the trait for each
   collection site and use it as the response (each case is a
   collection site). Then I will not need the collection site as random
   effect. However, the sample size is very small 1-4 plants. Is this a
   better approach than doing the analysis as logistic regression where
   each case is an individual?
3. Do I need to select the most uncorrelated variables? or random
   forest can handle many correlated variables?

Thank you.

Comment: You can check [mixed-effects random forest](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103730/how-can-i-include-random-effects-into-a-randomforest).