# Making binary prediction with GPBoost (or MERF)

Tags: machine-learning, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, binary-data, effects

My question is regarding this post from 1.5 years ago: [Modelling clustered data using boosted regression trees](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163435/modelling-clustered-data-using-boosted-regression-trees)

My label is a binary variable (yes/no). Is it possible to use GPBoost / MERF in order to make predictions for this binary variable? I wasn't able to find an answer to this question really quick. If no, which multilevel/mixed effects models can do this? I've already found Mixed Effects Logistic Regression.

Thanks,
Kind regards,
Olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can use binary response variables. In [`GPBoost`](https://pypi.org/project/gpboost/) we set `likelihood="binary"`. [`MERF`](https://pypi.org/project/merf/) in theory can also handle it, as based on the MERF's author's PhD thesis [here](http://biblos.hec.ca/biblio/theses/003002.PDF) binary outcomes are within the scope of the methodology but I see no such option in the `MERF` package itself.

I would suggest looking at [`bambi`](https://bambinos.github.io/bambi/main/index.html) (in Python/PyMC3) or [`rstanarm`](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/) (in R/Stan) too, you can define splines for your main fixed effects so they have non-linear influence in the response but also have a full MCMC approach in fitting the model and check the relevant diagnostics. (`statsmodels` often provides sub-optimal fitting results when dealing with mixed models.)

Comment: thanks! really clear, i will look into this !

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help!

Comment: I also have another question: The goal is to make a generalizable model, so that everyone can use the model. To make things more clear: Optimally, my test set does not have an ID column (the random effect). Is it still possible to make predictions or does the test set NEED an ID column? If yes, can I assign a random number to the test set ID in that case? In this github link: https://github.com/fabsig/GPBoost/blob/master/python-package/gpboost/sklearn.py the default for group_data_pred is None

Comment: I  think this is rather involved to answer in comments, can you please make a new question?

Comment: Ok yes, I made a new question!