# Generalizable model with GPBoost

Tags: machine-learning, mixed-model

I'm back with another question regarding my earlier asked question: [Making binary prediction with GPBoost (or MERF)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570601/making-binary-prediction-with-gpboost-or-merf/570629?noredirect=1#comment1054543_570629)

The goal of this project is to predict injuries, for which I only have a small subset of athletes available. This is a longitudinal study, since there are multiple individuals who have multiple observations. The model can be trained using a GPBoost/MERF algorithm. The training set contains x athletes and the test set contains y athletes. The athlete's ID will be the random effect. Optimally, my test set won't have an ID column (the random effect), because the goal is to make one model for the whole 'population'. Is it still possible to make predictions or does the test set NEED an ID column? If it's required, can I assign a random number to the test set ID in that case (like 999)? In this github link: github.com/fabsig/GPBoost/blob/master/python-package/gpboost/… the default for group_data_pred is None

If something is not clear, let me know, then I can edit the question.

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards,
Olivier

Comment: Random intercepts are not likely to [induce the correct within-person correlation structure](https://fharrell.com/post/re).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in GPBoost. You can simply assign a number (e.g, -1) which has not been observed in the training `group_data` / ID to the `group_data_pred` argument in the `predict` function. The predicted random effects will then be zero. Also, for the GPBoost algorithm, the predictions of the fixed and random effects are returned separately when setting `pred_latent=True` in the `predict` function. See [this Python example](https://github.com/fabsig/GPBoost/blob/master/examples/python-guide/GPBoost_algorithm.py#L113) for an example. You can then verify that all your predicted random effects (`random_effect_mean`) are indeed zero.

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way to predict? If you want to predict for new individuals, should this not be done integrating over the random effects distribution? Obviously, with a linear scale this would not make a difference for the point prediction (but would for prediction intervals), but if you work, say, on the logit scale for binary outcomes, this would make a difference. Right?

Comment: When having non-Gaussian data, this is what is being one in GPBoost when you predict the response variable (`pred_latent=False`). See the companion article https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9759834

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.