# Is there a difference between averaging individual regressions and including a random effect?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model, longitudinal-data-analysis, model-averaging

I have a bit of a theoretical question about random effects models and regression.  If I have a set of clustered, longitudinal data (say repeated measurements of $y$ on a number of different individuals) is there really any difference, aside for adjustments to degrees of freedom, perhaps, to fitting a regression model for each individual and averaging the parameter estimates across models to get an overall average model (i.e. all fixed effects) vs. fitting a model with individual id as a random effect in which each of the individual's observations fall (i.e a mixed model)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming you have an identical number of points per individual, or that you are doing a weighted averaging afterwards?

Comment: Incidentally, your question could also be reframed as: "What's the difference between including individual as a fixed effect vs. a random effect?". And I discuss this a bit in my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/289346/121522

Comment: @hi, mkt, I should have been more clear that I'm assuming equal sizes or weighted averaging.  Thanks for the link.  I'll give it a read now.

Comment: See Gelman's [the Secret Weapon](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2005/03/07/the_secret_weap/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's 3 cases to consider:

1. Separate linear regressions per individual
2. A single regression with a fixed effect for individual and an interaction term allowing individuals to have different slopes
3. A mixed model with random individual-level intercepts and slopes

1 and 2 are equivalent in terms of their mean predictions, though you're correct that the degrees of freedom & standard errors will differ. Since you don't care about that, I'll treat them as identical for purposes of comparing them against 3.

3 is different because of how random effects work: the individual-level random effects are *shrunk* towards zero i.e. you will tend to get less extreme values than you did in 1 & 2. This shrinkage is an important reason why random effects are valuable; it's not just about saving degrees of freedom.

A good description of why this works is in [this old article on Stein's paradox in statistics](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/other/Article1977.pdf)