There are statistical models for nonindependent/multilevel data (e.g., Mixed Models). Is there an approach for multilevel data in Machine Learning?
There are many cases of multilevel/nested/hierarchical data: people in schools, schools in counties, trials within a person, web sessions or mobile sessions within a person, etc.
In traditional statistics, there are various approaches for handling this sort of nested/hierarchical data that has non-independent observations: Mixed Effects Models, GEEs, and cluster corrected standard errors are a few methods.
However, what if you want to use Machine Learning methods/models with clustered/hierarchical data such as web sessions within a person? Is there an appropriate approach analogous to Mixed Effects Models for clustered/hierarchical data in an ML context? I understand that you need each observation to correspond to a unique observation/ID, so it doesn't seem like just apply a Linear Regression, XGBoost, Random Forest or whatever model to data with repeated values (Level-2, group-level data) and unique values (Level-1, repeated measures data) would be appropriate.
Is there any appropriate way to handle multilevel or repeated measures data that is clustered/nested within people in an ML context?

See this thread for a start: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221358/how-to-deal-with-hierarchical-nested-data-in-machine-learning/221376#221376
